# How to declare a vector to store contour using opencv 247 and visual studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to declare a vector for storing contour but I'm getting an error for the following:

**code:**

```
Rect bounding_rect;
vector<vector<Point>> contours; // Vector for storing contour
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
```

**errors:**

```
'Rect' undeclared identifier,
'Point' undeclared identifier,
'vector' unspecialized class template cant be used as a template argument,
'Vec4i' undefined,
```

Please could someone help me?

Comment: Are you sure your include files are proper and that you are linking to the correct libraries..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

either try :

```
cv::Rect
cv::Vec4i
cv::Point
```

or add:

```
using namespace cv;
```

after the headers